# read txt file with javascript in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

i'm trying to read text file that content this :

```
<p> copyright 2016 ..... </p>
```

from a file text in sharepoint library:URL

https://mydomaine.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/mysite/assets/footer.txt

using javascript and inject it in my html master page in  the footer `<footer></footer>`
any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the contents of a text file is relatively straightforward using an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

```
(function(){
    var serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile = "/sites/sitecollection/mysite/assets/footer.txt";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange=handler;
    req.open("GET", serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile, true); // params: (method, url, async)
    req.send();
    function handler(){
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
            // you can now access the file content via the responseText property
            document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }
})();
```

The above code is roughly equivalent to the following jQuery:

```
var serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile = "/sites/sitecollection/mysite/assets/footer.txt";
$.ajax({
    url: serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile,
    type: "GET"
}).done(handler);
function handler(data){
    $("footer").html(data);
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between the two codes? and wich one is recommended to use?

Comment: I personally recommend the first code example. The second one requires the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) to have already been loaded; I included it in case you were already using jQuery and wanted a shorter piece of code.

Comment: thank you it works just fine i have only one issue : somme characters are not displayed corectely , is it related to the encoding type? and how to resolve it ?

Comment: One option is to save your text file using UTF-8 encoding. (In Notepad, for example, choose "Save As" and in the save dialog you can change the Encoding from "ANSI" to "UTF-8".)