# How to display value from text file in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed, sharepoint-online

I don't have skill for coding , I just end-user to create the SharePoint intranet site.
and I have a question about how to display the value from text file in SharePoint modern pgae.
Could you please share the simple & easy coding to me?

I have tried to use JS modern script editor , but I don't have the code input it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read txt file with javascript in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104194/read-txt-file-with-javascript-in-sharepoint)

Comment: I tried , but the result show like this -->  : (function(){ var serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile = "https://xxxxxxxxx/Shared%20Documents/Text Value.txt"; var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); req.onreadystatechange=handler; req.open("GET", serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile, true); // params: (method, url, async) req.send(); function handler(){ if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){ // you can now access the file content via the responseText property document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML = req.responseText; } } })();

Comment: This part looks relevant: "you can now access the file content via the responseText property document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML = req.responseText;"